# Resetting a failed Horde installation on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, php

I first tried to install Horde Webmail by following the instructions on [horde.org](http://www.horde.org/apps/horde/docs/INSTALL) (ie PEAR install, like I did on my previous server, 7years ago) but it failed on connecting to mysql.

I then noticed that there is indeed a Horde Webmail package in Ubuntu (php-horde-webmail), so I removed the first installation and used ap-get to install that. Apt-get proceeded to install no less than 170 packages, so I guess there *was* a reason the first install didn't work.

But I then found that the webmail-install script would still pick up my installation destination path, and proceed to barf on that. I straced my way to find the link in .pearrc
As a first-time reader of said file, it looks to be more gibberish than structured to me (unbalanced { braces?!?). But deleting it just brings up yet another error from php:

```
Fatal Error:
Missing registry.php configuration file
In /usr/share/php/Horde/Registry.php on line 665

1. Horde_Core_Bundle->init() /usr/bin/webmail-install:30
2. Horde_Registry::appInit() /usr/share/php/Horde/Core/Bundle.php:60
3. Horde_Registry->__construct() /usr/share/php/Horde/Registry.php:279
4. Horde_Registry->_loadApplications() /usr/share/php/Horde/Registry.php:533
```

I googled around for an installation howto, but I have been unable to find any installation info about the php-horde-webmail on ubuntu 14.04.

Is my best bet really to go back and reinstall the entire server? That would be pretty hilarious.